# Why max(b,a) in Average Silhouette?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

Average Silhouette is one of the popular methods to decide number of clusters in a clustering algorithm.

Why should we use max(b,a) in the denominator of the formula? So why not just avg(a,b). I guess numerator is intuitive enough to understand. I am not able to wrap my head around denominator.

Comment: Probably to normalize the score for $[-1,1]$ range